# Capacious critical thinker - is this a correct usage of the word "capacious"?

Tags: word-usage

I just read on some internet page that a distinguished History professor at a leading California university described one of her students as a "capacious critical thinker".

Other than from the context, I wouldn't have understood "capacious", so I googled it up for its precise meaning. What I found left me wondering whether the professor might have gone for bombast and ended up using a word incorrectly!

I think I understand what she was trying to say but if "capacious" means "having a lot of space inside" or "roomy", I wonder whether it would be correct to say that someone who thinks deeply or thinks a lot is a capacious thinker? Meaning that the person (rather than the mind) is capacious?

Comment: I would be more likely to say someone has a "capacious intellect," but I wouldn't look askance at this professor's use of the term.

Answer (score -1):

adjective. Having a lot of space inside; roomy. 'Attorneys and judges in this bland, wood-paneled space all wear capacious robes patterned on the gowns of medieval European clerics.

https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/capacious